# passing null as array_keys second parameter

Tags: php

PHP documentation states that the [default value of array_keys second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) is *NULL*.

However, when passing *NULL* explicitly, array_keys does not seem to work properly.

---

### Example:

**code**

```
$a = array(10=>'a', 11=>'b', 12=>'b', 13=>'c', 14=>'c', 15=>'b');

$keys = array_keys($a);
var_dump($keys); //Output 0

$keys = array_keys($a, null);
var_dump($keys); //Output 1
```

**Output**

```
array
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 11
  2 => int 12
  3 => int 13
  4 => int 14
  5 => int 15

array
  empty
```

---

### Question

I reckon it must be trying to find keys whose value is null.

Passing false or empty string produces the exact same behavior (obviously).

**So, what is the default value?**

---

### Answer

[xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) [**answer is right**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900546/passing-null-as-array-keys-second-parameter/13900730#13900730). When inspecting the C code of this function, my first though was that this was a bad implementation at C level (and easily fixed by removing code)

**But then I realized this is actually the intended behavior** since they went to a lot of trouble to enable you to test for *NULL* values inside the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value is hard to explain here.

It is special case, the default value of second parameter is not actually the php's `NULL`, but the C level's `NULL`.

Dive into the source code:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(array_keys)
{
  zval *input,        /* Input array */
       *search_value = NULL,  /* Value to search for */
  //....
  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a|zb", &input, &search_value, &strict) == FAILURE) {
    return;
  }
  // ....
```

You could see, the default value is `NULL` for `search_value`, but if you specified the second parameter of `array_keys`, then after `zend_parse_parameters`, `search_value` will not be `NULL`.

Comment: Yup, that's it. (I actually went to have a look at the code before reading your answer). I first though this was a bad implementation at C level. But then inspecting the code with more care I realized this is actually the intended behavior or else you couldn't test for null values.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with xdazz. However, it seems that passing 0 works. Don't ask me how, though! (And, YMMV.)

```
$a = array(10=>'a', 'xaa'=>'b', 12=>'b', 13=>'c', 14=>'c', 15=>'b');

$keys = array_keys($a, 0);
var_dump($keys); //Output 0
```

Returns:

```
array(6) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> string(3) "xaa" [2]=> int(12) [3]=> int(13) [4]=> int(14) [5]=> int(15) }
```

Comment: Because of typecasting, since you passed int, all values in array are casted to int for comparison, and since all of them are not numeric string, they are equal to 0 after casting. Setting third parameter for `array_keys` to true will prevent it.

Comment: Makes sense. And by that token, any array values that aren't casted to 0 (ie, numerics and strings that start with a number) will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're searching for null, there's no result to give back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to infer from PHP manual as to the use of `search_value` parameter. I needed to do try an example.

```
If the optional search_value is specified,
then only the keys for **that** value are returned.
Otherwise, all the keys from the input are returned.
```

It means that when `search_value` is specified in `array_keys()`, the values in the array **(not keys)** are searched against `search_value`. If match occurs, the key for that value in `search_value` is returned.

## Example

```
<?                                                                         

$foo = array('first' => 'my_first',                                        
    'second' => 'my_second',                                               
    'third' => 'my_third',                                                 
    'fourth' => null);                                                     

$keys = array_keys($foo);                                                  
var_dump($keys); //Output 0                                                

$keys = array_keys($foo, 'my_second');                                                                                                                                                           
var_dump($keys); //Output 1                                                      

$keys = array_keys($foo, null);                                            
var_dump($keys); //Output 2                                                


?>
```

### Output

0:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
}
```

1:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "second"
}
```

2:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
}
```